# Calculating Cumulative elevation gain give me wierd results

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have the app that use `CoreLocation` and track user movement.
When user is walking or driving I save each coordinate to local database (lat/lng/alt) so I can draw route based on saved coordinates.
A few days ago I have added [Cumulative elevation gain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_elevation_gain) and I use this code in

```
didLocationUpdate:
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    netElevationGain += MAX(0, oldLocation.altitude - newLocation.altitude);
}
```

But something is just wrong.
I started the application and start walking and walking around for a few miles and I get `netElevationGain` almost 500 meters. Which no way it's correct.
This is the list of `netElevation` saved in database for each point:

```
0,41,43,44,47,52,55,62,73,80,91,100,114,140,146,153,159,180,199,208,228,240,259,275,320,329,349,359,366,375,381,392,408,419,428,437,446,449,462,469,478,486
```

Altitudes
`0.000000,181.678055,181.891495,182.786850,179.315399,177.035721,182.636307,181.259399,178.653015,192.552551,185.398819,182.693436,181.369766,154.306747,157.031693,159.748871,185.080856,198.080673,176.473877,178.646851,175.784424,178.184128,181.237488,188.956894,177.713181,193.673019,188.470184,182.749054,181.966507,181.547592,191.638657,198.713989,188.582977,197.977921,203.184540,205.108856,198.304123`
To display gain I use simple `select max(gain) from table where ...`

**UPDATE**

Now I get worse values (in descending order):
Alt:

```
200.334869,200.594666,196.293945,195.240234,191.800446,192.622375,179.951385,179.185577,179.681122,177.843719,183.459595,174.170502,0.000000
```

gain:

```
307,301,294,285,275,269,252,246,234,227,217,202,0
```

Comment: Have the values of `netElevation` been calculated from `altitudes` you  pasted below?

Comment: Yes. It's from same database. I store altitude and in the same time I store current netElevation. My main concern is that I think that this number should be smaller. So I wonder what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I also can not see how the elevation values correspond with your altitudes (for example, where does the value 41 come from?). You should print them together in a table. - Shouldn't it be `newLocation.altitude - oldLocation.altitude`? And you might have to ignore the first change `0 -> 181.678055`.

Comment: I don't know that's why I ask. So sit should be new - old why?

Comment: @1110: can you show full source of `- (void)locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`?

Comment: @1110: Because `new - old` is the *gain* in altitude, and is positive if the new altitude is greater than the old altitude, i.e. if you have climbed *up*.

Comment: So we made a mistake in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156415/how-to-calculate-elevation-like-in-runkeeper-application

Comment: @1110: It does indeed look like a mistake.

Comment: @1110: Well, in my understanding it should be the other way around. But you should log the values `oldLocation.altitude, newLocation.altitude, netElevationGain` in each update, and check if that is what you need.

Comment: Back to the train... back to the job... and after test I will probably be very grateful

Comment: @1110: But even with your code, I really cannot see how you get the values `0,41,43,44,...`.

Comment: I have updated my question. I use new - old but something is wired here :( too bad because emulator can't use altitude I don't know how to debug this :(

Comment: @1110: Could you add the following code to your didLocationUpdate method, and add the output to your question? `NSLog(@"old:%f, new:%f, gain:%f", oldLocation.altitude, newLocation.altitude, netElevationGain);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took the values you've listed and ran them as follows:

```
NSArray *altitudes = @[ @(0.000000), @(181.678055), @(181.891495), @(182.786850), @(179.315399), 
                        @(177.035721), @(182.636307), @(181.259399), @(178.653015), @(192.552551), 
                        @(185.398819), @(182.693436), @(181.369766), @(154.306747), @(157.031693), 
                        @(159.748871), @(185.080856), @(198.080673), @(176.473877), @(178.646851), 
                        @(175.784424), @(178.184128), @(181.237488), @(188.956894), @(177.713181), 
                        @(193.673019), @(188.470184), @(182.749054), @(181.966507), @(181.547592), 
                        @(191.638657), @(198.713989), @(188.582977), @(197.977921), @(203.184540), 
                        @(205.108856), @(198.304123) ];

float netAlt = 0.0f;

// Start with the third value as we're only interesting in net gain
for (NSInteger i = 2; i < altitudes.count; i++) {
    float oldAlt = [altitudes[i-1] floatValue];
    float newAlt = [altitudes[i] floatValue];

    // newAlt - oldAlt because we're interested in the 
    // difference between current and previous
    float diff = newAlt - oldAlt;

    netAlt += MAX(0, diff);
    printf("%.0f,", netAlt);
}
```

This produced the following output:

> 0,1,1,1,7,7,7,21,21,21,21,21,23,26,51,64,64,67,67,69,72,80,80,96,96,96,96,96,106,113,113,122,127,129,129

This seems reasonable and realistic to me. It's not at all clear how how you managed to get the values you have. They make no sense.

Comment: So I actually don't need to store gain to database at all as I can calculate it from only altitudes array?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the gain.

Comment: Today I was walking down the hill and use stored altitudes with your code. No ups. And I got 79 meters netgain. Should I sort data somehow or something? As I understand gain is just when you goes up.

Comment: No, there's no need to sort the data.

Comment: So what do you think is it possible to get 79 meters gain if I started at alt for example 200 and go down to 100 for example?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to gain 79m even though your end position is 100m lower than your start.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38714/discussion-between-1110-and-neilco)